# How to add content to sections programmatically in MVC / ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In each of my views, I am constantly adding a style and script associated with the view. It is convention in the application we introduced, but we want to automatically apply this convention instead.

Currently our views look like this:

```
<p>This is the view!</p>

@section styles {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Views/Home/Index.css" />
}

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Views/Home/Index.js"></script>
}
```

Is there a way to automate adding the styles and scripts? Perhaps in the base class of the controller, such as:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    string controller = RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    string action = RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    string script = string.Format("<script src=\"~/Views/{0}/{1}.js\"></script>", controller, action);
    string style = string.Format("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"~/Views/{0}/{1}.css\" />", controller, action); 

    // Todo: How to add script and style to sections programmatically???
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the controller/action name values in your views, and specifically, in your layout. Just edit your layout and in the head add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Views/@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"])/@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]).css" />
```

And before your closing body tag, add:

```
<script src="~/Views/@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"])/@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]).js"></script>
```

Comment: So simple I didn't even think about that! Thx!